# Are there any measures or for how much faster muscles atrophy when over 40 for type I and type II muscles?

Tags: exercise, muscle, age

Sarcopenia is muscle loss due to age

> Beginning as early as the 4th decade of life, evidence suggests that
> skeletal muscle mass and skeletal muscle strength decline in a linear
> fashion

Source: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4066461/

or more specifically an accelerated loss of type II muscles.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muscle_atrophy

Are are there measures of the difference or how was the conclusion reached?

Comment: Welcome to the Medical Sciences Stack. Please take a [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on the site and what we do here. Please note that we require questions that show evidence of research in an attempt to answer the question for themselves. Note that the wikipedia page on muscle atrophy has a section on sarcopenia which gives a simple explanation and definitions of both. You may wish to investigate Venn diagrams.